# Reading string and int for a matriix

Tags: c

so I'm trying to load info from a file like this:

```
TREE 1 2
BURN 5 6
...
```

Everything on my code is working well, but when it comes to the part of reading the file, it reads the 1st line and just get stuck there. Here is what I'm doing:

```
int lines=0, columns=0, MAX=5;
FILE *file=NULL;
char *string;

...

string=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);

while ((fscanf(file, "%s %d %d", string, &lines, &colums))!=EOF) { 
    matrix[lines][colums]=string;
    string=NULL;
}
```

This is the only part of the code that is not working properly, everything else works fine. File opens, matrix properly allocated. it just gets blocked on the 1 line. The "..." is just the part of allocating the 40x40 matrix.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't compare `fscanf()` to `EOF`, read the documentation. Doing so is assuming that it did read, also white spaces are meaningless in this format specifier just, "%s%d%d" is ok.

Comment: Don't use `fscanf` to read formatted input. Read lines of text with `fgets` and then read the formatted data from the buffer `fgets` returns with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading information from a file into a matrix isn't difficult, but there are a number of aspects of your code that are perplexing. To begin, it appears you are creating a `40 x 40` matrix, and then reading a *4-character* string along with its intended `row` and `column` position in your `40 x 40` matrix, While there is nothing wrong with creating a partially populated matrix, the approach you have taken has several trouble spots.

As pointed out, checking `fscanf(...) != EOF)` is incorrect. The `Xscaf` family of functions returns a *match-count* equal to the number of successful conversions that take place based on your *format-string*. For example, with a format string of `"%s %d %d"`, the *match-count* (and therefore the `return` of `fscanf`) for a successful read and conversion of a line into `string`, `lines` and `columns` would be `3`. The proper use of the `return` would be to check for `3` valid conversions. e.g.:

```
fscanf (file, "%s %zu %zu", string, &lines, &columns) == 3)
```

(as others have noted it is probably better to read the lines of the file using a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` to protect against stray characters in the file following `columns`, or other format issues, leading to read or conversion failures. However, if you are guaranteed to have a consistent format throughout your input file, you can non-optimally use `fscanf` in this situation)

You also have two additional issues you should check during your read and assignment to `matix`. First, you should keep track of the row index to insure you do now write beyond the end of `matrix` (e.g. attempting to write 41 row, etc..). For example with `idx` tracking the index for the number of rows read/added and with `ROWS` being a constant `40` you could do something similar to:

```
while (idx < ROWS &&    /* read each line, validate conversion */
       fscanf (file, "%s %zu %zu", string, &lines, &columns) == 3) {
...

    idx++;
}
```

Second, you need to check the value of `lines` against `40`, and `columns` along with the length of the string (including the *nul-terminator*) to insure it does not extend beyond the end of `matix` (e.g. place characters beyond `row or column 39`. Assuming your string has a maximum length of `5` (4-chars + 1) and a constant `COLS` defined as `40`, you could do something like the following at the beginning of your read loop:

```
    if (lines >= ROWS) { /* validate row position for string */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid row index, line '%zu'\n",
                idx);
        continue;
    }

    if (columns + MAX + 1 >= COLS) { /* validate position for string */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid columns + MAX, line '%zu'\n",
                 idx);
        continue;
    }
```

If you intend to print `matrix` as strings to confirm your code, you must also deal with the characters between column `0` and the beginning of `string` placed at column `columns`. That can be handled with a quick `memset` if needed. e.g.:

```
    memset (matrix[lines], ' ', columns);
```

(You also need to confirm if `lines` and `columns` read from your file are *zero*-based or *one*-based)

Lastly, there is no need to dynamically declare `string`. You know `string` cannot exceed `40`, and for purposes of your example input, it doesn't exceed `5`, so a simple static declaration of a character array of size `5` is sufficient.

Putting all the pieces together, and adding a `maxrow` limit simply for print purposes of the example, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 40
#define COLS 40
#define MAX 5

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char matrix[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};
    char string[MAX] = {0};
    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    size_t lines, columns, idx, maxrow, i;
    lines = columns = idx = maxrow = i = 0;

    if (!file) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (idx < ROWS &&    /* read each line, validate conversion */
        fscanf (file, "%s %zu %zu", string, &lines, &columns) == 3) {

        if (lines >= ROWS) { /* validate row position for string */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid row index, line '%zu'\n",
                    idx);
            continue;
        }

        if (columns + MAX + 1 >= COLS) { /* validate position for string */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid columns + MAX, line '%zu'\n",
                    idx);
            continue;
        }

        memset (matrix[lines], ' ', columns);     /* set leading spaces    */
        strcpy (&matrix[lines][columns], string); /* copy string to matrix */

        maxrow = lines > maxrow ? lines : maxrow; /* track max row filled  */
        idx++;
    }
    if (file != stdin) fclose (file);

    for (i = 0; i < maxrow + 1; i++)  /* simple test print of matrix */
        printf (" %s\n", matrix[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if your compiler cannot handle input/conversion to `size_t` (e.g. `%zu`), you can change the declarations to `int`. The purpose in choosing `size_t` is that `lines` and `columns` can never be *negative*. Choosing an appropriate type allows the compiler to provide additional warnings)

**Compile**

Always compile with *warning enabled*. Example:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/matrix_strings matrix_strings.c
```

(if not using `gcc`, you compiler will have similar options)

**Example/Output**

Using your example input file would result in the following:

```
$ ./bin/matrix_strings ../dat/tb.txt

   TREE



       BURN
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((fscanf(file, "%s %d %d", string, &lines, &colums))!=EOF) { 
    matrix[lines][colums]=string;
    string=NULL;
}
```

You should not set your string pointer to `NULL`. That way it becomes a `NULL pointer`, and in the next loop you try to `fscanf()` to a NULL pointer, and will also leak the allocated memory.

The read in `lines` and `colum(n)s` could be higher than your `40x40 matrix`. It would be better to check this.

Also: the return value of [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) can be something else than `EOF`:

> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (**feof or ferror**). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

```
matrix[lines][colums]=string;
```

Here, your are storing the `pointer` in `matrix[][]`, not the string content. You need to use something like [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) here.

You need to check the names of your variables too:

```
columns=0
, &colums)
matrix[lines][colums]
```

colums vs colum**n**s.

Comment: Why not suggest checking `fscanf(file, "%s %d %d", string, &lines, &colums)) != 3)` to indicate failed conversion? That is the primary purpose for returning the *match count*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy a string just using `=`. Use `strcpy()` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int lines = 0, columns = 0;
    char string[5];
    char matrix[40][40][5];
    FILE *file = NULL;
    if ((file = fopen("source.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((fscanf(file, "%s %d %d", string, &lines, &columns)) != EOF)
    {
        strcpy(matrix[lines][columns], string);
        printf("matrix[%d][%d]:%s\n", lines, columns, matrix[lines][columns]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```